# vaadin combobox addItem and option value(?)

Tags: combobox, vaadin

code

```
       ComboBox combo = new ComboBox('comboBox');
       combo.addItem("A");
       combo.addItem("B");
       combo.addItem("C");
       combo.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

            com.vaadin.data.Property changedProeprty = event.getProperty();
            String value = changedProeprty.toString() ;
        }
    });
```

value is 'C'

However I want to input the other value, like selectBox's option in html

```
      <select>
         <option value="1">A</option>
         <option value="2">B</option>
         <option value="3">C</option>
       </select>
```

How to input the option value and how to get the option value in vaadin combobox ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the "real" value as the items in your ComboBox.
You can then use the setItemCaption(...) method to tell the system what do display in the UI.

```
// Set item caption for this item explicitly
select.addItem(2);
select.setItemCaption(2, "Demos");
```

Look in the book of vaadin for more details [here](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.selection.html#components.selection.captions)

Comment: Is there no way to do this using the declarative syntax only?

Comment: Not sure, but since the question was shown with code, it was not the scope of the question